# How to set a value in register with set_facts in ansible?

Tags: ansible

When a task is skipped on the basis of condition and the result of register also differ which cause of another task has been failed.

```
- name: Check if the partition is already mounted
  shell: df | grep "{{item.partition}}" | wc -l
  with_items:
    - "{{ ebs_vol }}"
  register: ebs_checked
  when: ebs_vol is defined

- name: Make filesystem of the partition
  filesystem: fstype=ext4 dev={{item.item.partition}} force=no
  when:  ( ebs_vol is defined and "{{item.stdout}} == True" )
  changed_when: True
  with_items:
    - ebs_checked.results
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `default` filter to handle corner cases:

```
- name: Make filesystem of the partition
  filesystem: fstype=ext4 dev={{item.item.partition}} force=no
  when:  item.stdout | bool
  changed_when: True
  with_items: "{{ ebs_checked.results | default([]) }}"
```

This will iterate over empty list (read "will do nothing") if there is no `results` in `ebs_checked`.

Also you should not check for `ebs_vol is defined` because `when` statement in looped tasks is applied inside a loop, and keeping in mind that you check for `ebs_vol is defined` in the previous task, makes this check unnecessary inside a loop.

Comment: In the above solution at - 
when:  item.stdout | bool
 is bool a datatype or variable that we need to use ?

Comment: It is a filter that converts strings to boolean type appropriate for `when` condition. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: it's giving the syntax error. dict object has no attribute stdout.

Comment: check what's in the `ebs_checked.results`

Comment: I am stuck when I will not define ebs_vol and the output is below as there is not stdout in result. 
debug msg={{ ebs_checked.results}}] ************************
ok: [10.254.18.117] => {
    "msg": "[{u'skipped':"
}